# Understanding the streaming concept in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, csv, events, stream

I am trying to convert a CSV data to JSON data while streaming from a HTTP url by using "csvtojson" package.

```
 const csv = require("csvtojson");
 const request = require('request');
 let options = {
    uri: '',
    ****
 };
 let tempArr = [];
 csv()
    .fromStream(request(options))
    .on("json", (jsonObj) => {
        if (JSON.parse(jsonObj.Response).intents[0].intent == "None")
            tempArr.push(JSON.parse(jsonObj.Response));
    })
    .on('done', (error) => {
        callback(null, tempArr)
    })
```

This is calling under an API. When I starts the server and call this api to convert csv to json, it works perfectly.
And If I call the same API again, the "json" event is not getting triggered, Instead "done" event is triggered directly.

i.e., the streaming is not done from the second time. why is it behaving like this?

and what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks to me like the stream is kept between the calls, and it's empty on the second one, because it is already drained.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. so what could be a solution for this?

Comment: I don't know node.js, but can you get the data from the stream once, than keep them, and use the data (instead of the stream) every time you need CSV?